Is there any logic for using betting average rather than best odds?
There is a question about the predictive power of betting markets compared to polling.  Two articles that discus this are Forbes and Fortune, and Forbes references Real Clear Politics (RCP) betting average.  I cannot find anything that specifies what exactly RCP betting average is, but Compare bet specify "mean average implied probability to get a consensus view across the betting industry".
When comparing multiple polls it is common, though not universally accepted to consider an arithmetic mean of those available, as it seems from that question RCP use mean for polls.  While there are arguments against, the argument that IF polls were independent unbiased random samples then an arithmetic mean would provide a more accurate measure of the true population than any one datapoint is valid.
It seems hard to make such an argument for betting markets.  I would have thought the best odds available at any point would be a better indication of the position of the market.  Why is average odds used in such predictions not best odds?
Evidence for a difference
One way to look at this is the real odds offered today.  This is the oddschecker matrix for US Presidential Election - Winner Betting Odds:

Looking at Trump, there is a 10% difference between the worst and best odds, but the big difference is Vance.  The bookmakers offer between 67 - 101 and the matchbook offers 235.  The arithmetic mean is 100.7, less than half the best odds available.  It seems at least plausible that the bookmakers are exploiting low information punters and the matchbook, where individuals can lay either side of the bet, is a better representative of the position of a hypothetical efficient market.  Such an efficient market would be assumed to give the more information about the true probability of an event than one dominated by low information perhaps recreational gamblers.  This is an extreme example with a low probability event, but the effect seems likely to be present to some extent frequently.
Another example, which is very different and cannot be assumed to accurately represent the political gambling market but does allow you to easily draw graphs of a relatively inefficient "crowd-sourced" market that is at least related to gambling is decentralised cryptocurrency markets.  If we compare the offers available on some different markets:



Viewed like this it seems intuitive that the market is best represented by some metric based on the best offers in each direction.  I do not know what the offers that are far from this value represent, but it is hard to see that they tell us more about the underlying reality that these prices are supposed to represent than the best offers.
Also of note is how the shape of these graphs will change the arithmetic mean significantly, as would how you weight the offers by volume.  This seems to detract from the potential value of the metric.

Averaging is commonly used for combining statistically independent estimators of the same underlying variable. Also I'm not sure this issue is unique to politics. You might get better answers at crossvalidated or another statistics centered stack exchange.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution The concept of using betting markets to estimate true and impactful probabilities is a particular question in politics as demonstrated by the linked Forbes and Fortune articles.  It is not really a maths question, but an interpretation question that seems more relevant here.

But the underlying reason is surely math. You want an as unbiased and minimal variance estimator as possible and math says that under certain circumstances arithmetic averaging is doing that. The thing left to show is if these assumptions hold in this case.

This Q is better suited for the Economics or Statistics Stack Exchange sites.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution "But the underlying reason is surely math" That underlying reason is what I am asking for.  It could be math, like the central limit theorem that is used to justify mean for polls.  It could be data/statistics, which is used to compare betting and polling predictive power by forbes/fortune.  The answer to this question would consist of statements by experts or authorities, which seems to be politics.
